# R - using substitute within a nested function

Tags: r, substitution

I have a function that may end up being nested (`Inner`) and some other function (in general this function won't be known) that I'm calling `Outer`, and I would like `Inner` to be able to produce the same result regardless of the wrapper function (`Outer`in the below case).

```
Inner <- function(x,baz,bang){
  # code stuff things ...
  x.prime = as.character(substitute(x))
  return(c(x.prime,y,z))
}

Outer <- function(y){
  Inner(y)
}
Inner(a)
# "a" "stuff" "things" , which is what I'm expecting, in particular the "a".
Outer(a)
# "y" .... , but I was expecting to get "a"?
```

Of course I'm not dead set on using substitute if someone knows of a better method.

Does anyone have any clues how to get Inner to output the same result regardless if it is nested or not?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide some details about what you're trying to accomplish here?

Comment: This code is helpful for simple translations to another programming language, essentially I want to see if I don't have to force the users to use double quotes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a general outline that should help you solve your problem:

```
Inner <- function(x) {
  my.call <- quote(substitute(x))    # we quote this here because we are going to re-use this expression
  var.name <- eval(my.call)

  for(i in rev(head(sys.frames(), -1L))) { # First frame doesn't matter since we already substituted for first level, reverse since sys.frames is in order of evaluation, and we want to go in reverse order
    my.call[[2]] <- var.name         # this is where we re-use it, modified to replace the variable
    var.name <- eval(my.call, i)
  }
  return(var.name)
}
Outer <- function(y) Inner(y)
Outer2 <- function(z) Outer(z)
```

Now let's run the functions:

```
Inner(1 + 1)
# 1 + 1
Outer(2 + 2)
# 2 + 2
Outer2(3 + 3)
# 3 + 3
```

Inner always returns the outermost expression (you don't see `y` or `z` ever, just the expression as typed in `.GlobalEnv`.

The trick here is to use `sys.frames()`, and repeatedly `substitute` until we get to the top level.

Note this assumes that all the "Outer" functions just forward their argument on to the next inner one.  Things likely get a lot more complicated / impossible if you have something like:

```
Outer <- function(y) Inner(y + 1)
```

This code does not check for that type of issue, but you probably should in your code.  Also, keep in mind that the assumption here is that your functions will only be called from the R command line.  If someone wraps their functions around yours, you might get unexpected results.

Comment: Thank you for the working solution as well as the thorough explanation.

Comment: I'm not sure if your above limitation is true. I've tried (with your def of Inner) Outer<-function(y) Inner(y+1); Outer2<-function(z) Outer(z+5) and for Outer2(r) I get r + 5 + 1 (with type language
). Maybe I misunderstood your note?

Comment: @csta, it may not be a limitation.  I hadn't tested it, but was concerned it might not work.  Looks like it isn't based on your test.